# Left Panel Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

All webpage design is reponsive. There is one fixed header, body container and left menu. When icon clicked on the top menu, there will be left menu opening onto body container.

There is 2 problem:

1. On left menu, I cannot scroll vertically.
2. While trying to scroll, body is scrolling.

My CSS:

```
body {
color:#000;
background-color:#ffffff;
max-width: 99.2%;
margin: 0;
}

#container
{
font-family: 'Open Sans',Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
width: 99.2%;
margin: 0;
background: #FFF;
padding: 2em 0.5em;
}

.leftmenu
{
display: none;
min-width: 30%;
max-width: 90%;
background: #262626;
z-index: 999;
min-height: 200em;
color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.leftmenuContainer
{
margin-left: 0.5em;
width: 95%;
}
```

JQuery open function:

```
$(".menuIcon").click(function () {
        $('.leftmenu').toggle( "slide" );
        });
```

Thank you...

Edit: If someone have same problem, solution is given below. But there is something little disturbing that on iOS, after you reach the end of scrolling, parent object (#container in this code) begins to scroll again. To avoid this, add this line to .leftmenu:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: Is there a URL where the site can be seen?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this one?

Comment: [link](http://teknovole.com/testsite) but Krisna and Ronald's solution solved the problem, thank you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give `.leftmenu` a height or max-height and set overflow to auto.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting height to 100% in `.leftmenu`.

Comment: Thank you Krishna, your solution also fixes the problem but I gave check to Ronald because of giving right answer before you. I think this is fair judgement.